# How can I create a shortcut task for a single test in Gradle?

Tags: testing, gradle, api-design

In Gradle, I can run a single test from the command line as follows:

```
gradle -Dtest.single=VeryCriticalTestX test
```

`VeryCriticalTestX` is frequently executed alone, and I'd like to provide a more readable and flexible API to my fellow developers. Ideally, they would only need to run

```
gradle testCritical
```

without worrying about the test's name. This would also allow me to change the name over time without breaking Jenkins builds.

How do I do achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle's `Test`-Tasks can be configured to only include tests matching a given name pattern. You can create a new task `testCritical` as follows:

```
task testCritical(type: Test) {
    group = 'verification'
    description = 'Runs a very critical test'

    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

    include('**/VeryCriticalTestX.class')
}
```

With this, renaming `VeryCriticalTestX` to something else doesn't break other people's commands or Jenkins jobs. However, there is the risk that someone accidentally disables this task by renaming the `VeryCriticalTestX` without adapting the task configuration. This can be prevented with the following `TaskExecutionListener`:

```
// verify that testCritical is not skipped unexpectedly due to a renamed classfile
// we detect this using Gradle's NO-SOURCE TaskState
gradle.addListener(new TaskExecutionListener() {
  void beforeExecute(Task task) {}
  void afterExecute(Task task, TaskState state) {
    if (checkJooqEnumBindings.equals(task) && state.getNoSource()) {
       throw new GradleException("testCritical did not run because it couldn't find VeryCriticalTestX")
    }
  }
})
```